# Fully connected graphs with known edge lengths

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

It is my belief that, given a set of edge lengths for a complete graph, there is only one arrangement of nodes that fulfills those edge lengths. (i.e., if I tell you that the edge lengths are {4, 4, 3, 5, 7, 10}*, but not which nodes go with which edges, there is only one way to arrange the 4 nodes, not counting reflections.)

Can anyone confirm/deny with proof?

*(Don't use these specific numbers, they're made up. Probably no graph exists that corresponds to these.)﻿

Comment: Shall we assume the graph is drawn in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: are rotations the same ?  reflections ?

Comment: okay I guess I don't get the concept of edge length without a plane  I guess maybe path length might work better.

Comment: Sorry, yes. 2d, rotations and reflections do not count.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $4$ vectors 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\0   \\0   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\0   \\3   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\4   \\0   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{39}}{2}   \\ 2    \\ \frac{3}{2}   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
The distance between each of these vectors is summarised in the following distance matrix
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 5 & 4    \\
3 & 0 & 4 & 4    \\
5 & 4 & 0 & 4    \\
4 & 4 & 4 & 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Now consider the $4$ vectors 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\0   \\0   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\0   \\3   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\\frac{\sqrt{55}}{2}   \\\frac{3}{2}   \\
\end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\frac{150}{11}}   \\ \sqrt{\frac{5}{44}}    \\ \frac{3}{2}   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
The distance between each of these vectors is summarised in the following distance matrix
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 4 & 4    \\
3 & 0 & 4 & 4    \\
4 & 4 & 0 & 5    \\
4 & 4 & 5 & 0    \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Both tetrahedra have distances $ \{ 3,4,4,4,4,5 \}$. In the first tetrahedron the lengths $3$ and $5$ are adjacent to one another, but in the second terahedron they are opposite.